# Curve fitting non-linear 3D surfaces in C#

Tags: c#, .net, curve-fitting

In my C# application, I have an array of 3D spacial measurements (x, y, z) of a surface. I need to create a curve fit of that surface (something like a cubic spline fit, but in 3D) so I can estimate the z of any x,y location.

In Python, I would do something similar to this:

```py
file = 'mydata.csv'
x, y, z = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter=',', unpack=True)
interpolator = interpolate.RBFInterpolator(np.array([x, y]).transpose(), z)
print(interpolator(np.array([[1, 2]]))) # prints [{z-value at 1, 2}]
```

I've tried using the MathNet.Numerics library to do this, but cannot find any curve-fitting functions that can do more than just flat surfaces.

```
private void Example(Coordinate[] coordinates)
{
    double[][] coordinatePairs = coordinates.Select(coor => new double[] { coor.x, coor.y }).ToArray();
    double[] zValues = coordinates.Select(coor => coor.z).ToArray();
    var func = MathNet.Numerics.Fit.MultiDimFunc(coordinatePairs, zValues);
    Console.WriteLine(func(new double[] { 1, 2 }));
}
```

For a spherical surface, for instance, the above calculates the z to be 0 at every position on the sphere. (FYI, the actual surface I am mapping is more like a disk with a "roughened" surface - the sphere was only an example).

Is there any kind of general purpose, 3D curve-fitting library or function out there? What's the standard, if any?

Comment: have you tried switching to polar coordinates? Perhaps MathNet can model  spheric surface as  elevation= F(long, lat);

Comment: @alexm That's a good idea (I can use something like [this SO answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/120740) to convert my measurements to lat/long/elevation). However, latitude and longitude are dependent on z, so I can't use that interpolation with only x,y as my input (i.e., `func(x, y)` would not be possible).

Comment: As you mention RBF interpolation in the NumPy library, would a similar method work for you? I found an article from the VS magazine that covers the method in detail. https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/03/12/create-radial-basis-function.aspx?m=1

Comment: @VolatilePulse Thank you for the link; if I intend to write my own RBF interpolator, I would probably use that for ground work. For this question, though, I would really like an already-made library that I can rely upon.